# Loosing ratio when resizing window with svg <embed>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to insert svg images with the  tag, but the problem is when I resize the browser window(make it smaller) I lose the aspect ration, especially when resizing vertically. The images tend to lose the distance beetwen each other when they get smaller. Has anybody come across a similar problem?

```
https://jsfiddle.net/bh7gz06q/
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="Interaktywny poradnik szybkiego startu dla Brackets.">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>



<div class="container">
<embed class="imgelement" src="https://www.drawsvg.org/home/img/picture.svg" id="embed1" width="15%" height="auto" type="image/svg+xml" style="position:absolute;left:50%;top:0%"></embed>
<embed class="imgelement" src="https://www.okcode.pl/img/bg-square.svg" id="embed" width="15%" height="auto" type="image/svg+xml" style="position:absolute;left:50%;top:40%;z-index:3"></embed>
<embed class="imgelement" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg" id="embed2" width="15%" height="auto" type="image/svg+xml" style="position:absolute;left:50%;top:70%;z-index:2"></embed>
</div>


</script>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

top:40% and top:70% is still holding true when you resize vertically, so they overlap. Is there are reason you are using absolute positioning there?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. I'm using 3 svg images, using z-index to put them in layers. And then I need to make the first to layers clickable. so I need to move the 1st layers down a bit so I can click on the 2nd layers.